Blender 4.2 Eevee - Volumetrics show up differently between Viewport, Render and Command Line Render
Basically, I found that there is a major inconsistency in how Volumetrics in Eevee Next are rendered out depending on exactly how you render it out.
At this point I've ruled out running into VRAM limits, since while I only have 4GB of VRAM, an acquaintance proceeded to achieve basically exactly the same results with his 72GB of VRAM. So I now have absolutely no idea what's causing this massive difference in rendering.
This is how it looks like while in Viewport

This is how it looks when I try to render it out in Blender itself

This is how it looks when I try to render it out in command line

This is the .bat file command I use, in case it matters
"%blenderExePath%" -b "Frenzied Flame Animation.blend" -x 1 -a


Well, I've managed to get it to work, but I've had to disable actual volumetrics entirely, i.e. the Density, leaving exclusively Emissive Volumets.
Annoying, but functional.
